# Did Narcissa and Andromeda stay in contact?

Tags: harry-potter

Did Narcissa Black and Andromeda stay in contact? We know that Andromeda married a  Muggle-born and Bellatrix stopped being in contact with her. But do we have proof Narcissa did? We know that Bellatrix says

> Narcissa and I haven't spoken to our sister since she married that filthy mudblood

Narcissa doesn't comment. Perhaps she's feeling guilty because she does keep in contact with Andromeda?

Answer (score 5):

## There is not enough information to know.

It is not possible to know for certain whether Narcissa ever spoke with Andromeda after Andromeda married a Muggle-born. Bellatrix surely cut off all contact with her, and undoubtedly believes Narcissa did as well. Neither Narcissa nor Andromeda have mentioned themselves whether they have ever spoken after the marriage, and no evidence has been seen either way. However, Narcissa not verbally agreeing with Bellatrix  does not mean she therefore disagreed. Because of her discomfort at the general situation of Lord Voldemort’s presence in their house, Narcissa never spoke a single word during what is shown of the Death Eaters’ meeting.

> “Malfoy glanced sideways at his wife. She was staring straight ahead, quite as pale as he was, her long, blonde hair hanging down her back, but beneath the table her slim fingers closed briefly on his wrist.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 1 (The Dark Lord Ascending)*</sup></sub>

When the Malfoys are directly asked whether they are pleased to share their home with Voldemort, she does not say a word, only nods. In this case, she also
does not agree with the statement she was supposed to make, which was that she is pleased to host Voldemort, but this displeasure is the root of her continued silence. She does not want to respond to anything at all.

> “To Malfoy’s left, his wife made an odd, stiff nod, her eyes averted from Voldemort and the snake.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 1 (The Dark Lord Ascending)*</sup></sub>

She also does not respond when Voldemort asks her son whether he would babysit Tonks’s half-werewolf offspring, and this is almost certainly not because she planned to let Draco babysit for Tonks and Lupin’s then-hypothetical future offspring.

> “What say you, Draco?’ asked Voldemort, and though his voice was quiet, it carried clearly through the catcalls and jeers. ‘Will you babysit the cubs?’
>
> The hilarity mounted; Draco Malfoy looked in terror at his father, who was staring down into his own lap, then caught his mother’s eye. She shook her head almost imperceptibly, then resumed her own deadpan stare at the opposite wall.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 1 (The Dark Lord Ascending)*</sup></sub>

While there is no proof either way whether or not Narcissa ever spoke to Andromeda again, Narcissa’s lack of agreement to Bellatrix’s statement is only evidence that her reluctance to speak at all with Voldemort present in her house.

Comment: Thanks for this answeer

Comment: It was a Lando Calrissian moment: "This deal is getting worse all the time."

Comment: Although Draco may have salvaged the situation by saying, "If I can practice curses on them, maybe."